# Unable to select future date from date picker view

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I am unable to select future dates from the date picker view. I would like to be able to select only current and future dates, not past dates.

```
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: EnterAccountCell2.self), for: indexPath) as! EnterAccountCell2

    cell.inputTextField.title = NSLocalizedString("StartDate", comment: "")
    cell.inputTextField.delegate = self
    cell.inputTextField?.placeholder = NSLocalizedString("PleaseSelect", comment: "")
    cell.inputTextField.titleFont = UIFont(name: UIConfiguration.getUIFONTAPP(), size: UIConfiguration.kFontSizeMedium)!
    cell.inputTextField.tag = 222
    cell.inputTextField.inputView = UIView(frame: .zero)
    cell.inputTextField.text = self.myDateShow
    cell.datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerChanged(picker:)), for: .valueChanged)
    cell.selectView.isHidden = false
    cell.inputTextField.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.datePickerView.minimumDate = Date()
    cell.datePickerView.maximumDate = Date(timeInterval: 10976*24*60*60, since: Date())
   
return cell

}
```

Comment: I am able to scroll the date picker, but I am not able to select future dates. I want to be able to select only current and future dates, not past dates.

Comment: Your code seems like it should work. I wonder if a date 30 years in the future is too large? You might try changing 10976*24*60*60 to 10976.0*24.0*60.0*60.0 so the compiler does that math with Doubles. I would also try a Date not so far into the future as a test. –

Comment: I just did a quick test and the code posted in the question seems to work just fine. I added the date picker to a view controller via a storyboard. I added a target-action method via code, just like above, set a minimum date and maximum date just like above. I am able to select dates from today until 25-February-2053. So it may very-well be something apart from the date-picker itself that is preventing the selection. (This is just to confirm what @DuncanC said about the code looking like it should work).

Answer (score -1):

To allow users to select only current and future dates, you can set the minimumDate property of the datePickerView to the current date, and the maximumDate property to the maximum date that you want to allow the user to select. For example, to allow users to select dates up to 30 days in the future, you can use the following code:

```
cell.datePickerView.minimumDate = Date()
cell.datePickerView.maximumDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 30, to: Date())
```

This code sets the minimumDate to the current date and the maximumDate to 30 days from the current date, so users will be able to select any date within the next 30 days but not any past dates. If you want to allow a different number of days into the future, you can adjust the value passed to the date(byAdding:value:to:) method accordingly.

Comment: I am able to scroll the date picker, but I am not able to select future dates. I want to be able to select only current and future dates, not past dates.

Comment: Your "answer" tells the OP to do what they are already doing. How is that hepful?